# Why smart contract function fails with "Error 3090004: Missing required authority"?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, c++, contract-name, contract-development

**WHAT I WANT**

From the contract `mycontract` I want to call a function `function1`. 
The function `function1` calls another function of `mycontract` called `function2`. The function `function2` calls an action of another contract `othercontr`.
Both `function1` and `function2` use `_self`inside.

`user --> function1(...) --> function2(_self, ...)-->action[of othercontract]`

**WHAT IS WORKING**

If I call directly `function2(_self, ...)`, the function receives correctly `_self` and works fine.

**WHAT IS NOT WORKING**

I tried the following options as `function2` arguments:

1. `_self` is not recognized ad does not compile;
2. `N(_self)` gives the error: "Error 3050000: Action validate exception; inline action's authorizing actor .self does not exist";
3. `N(mycontract)` gives the error in the section ERROR.

**CRIME SCENE**

```
checksum256 result = function1(paramA, paramB);

checksum256 function1(uint8_t paramA, uint8_t paramB) {
    ...
    // Option 1. function2(_self, paramC, paramD);        
    // Option 2. function2(N(_self), paramC, paramD);
    // Option 3.
    function2(N(mycontract), paramC, paramD);
    ...
}

checksum256 function2(account_name user, uint8_t paramC, uint8_t paramD) {
    ... 
    // Calling the action "actionname" of the contract "mycontract".
    // The action "actionname" saves in a table the param "user", which is the action caller.   
    action(
      permission_level{user, N(active)},
      N(othercontr), N(actionname),
      std::make_tuple(user, paramC, paramD)
    ).send();
    ...
}
```

**ERROR**

> Error 3090004: Missing required authority Ensure that you have the
>   related authority inside your transaction!; If you are currently using
>   'cleos push action' command, try to add the relevant authority using
>   -p option.

Comment: when you calling the action whose permission are you providing at that time .?

Comment: As written in the code, the permission is provided inside the `function2` body: `permission_level{user, N(active)},`

Comment: I mean when you call the action using cleos.

Comment: `cleos push action mycontract function0 '[]' -p  mycontract@active`

Comment: N(othercontr), othercontr should be the account with which you set your contract, and one more thing did you set the permission of `mycontract`?

Comment: 1. The account I use is called `mycontract` as well. 2. `cleos set account permission mycontract active '{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS...","weight":1}],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"mycontract","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p mycontract@owner`

Comment: Can we have a look at `require_auth(get_self());` in the contract  , have you given hardcoded contract name or like `get_self()`.

Comment: you are setting permission of `mycontract` with actor `mycontract` that is strange. It mean you set your contract with `mycontract`. so while calling action in your account you should use` N(mycontract)` instead of `N(othercontr)`.

Comment: One more thing actor is the account with which you set your contract.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried `N(mycontract)`, but it gives the error in the section ERROR. On the other side, I think I have another error inside some code I did not post; probably ,the issue is there, because I don't set `_self `during an `emplace` operation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was inside an `emplace()`.

Basically, I was not setting the payer. After, hard coding the payer as `N(mycontract)`, I don't get the error anymore and the functions work correctly.